# Displaying Row Count for Data in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Been at this awhile...this is actually another simplified question to a problem I posted earlier.  I'm trying to display the country and count for the following query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(id), country FROM users GROUP BY country ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $countries = $row['country'];
    echo $countries;}
```

What I'm getting in output is the countries listed from highest to lowest, but it does not have the count displayed next to it.  I know these have been summed in the query, how do I target the number & assign it to a php variable for display?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add alias in query for `COUNT(id)` like below:-

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(id) as count, country FROM users GROUP BY country ORDER BY count DESC");
```

Now change `while()` loop code a bit:-

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { // _assoc for lighter array iteration
    $countries = $row['country'];
    $countries_count = $row['count'];// get count of each country
    echo $countries.'--'.$countries_count ;// show country and it's count both 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alias for your COUNT column and then reference that in the array returned by mysqli_fetch_array for each row.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(id) AS countryCount, country FROM users GROUP BY countryCount ORDER BY countryCount DESC");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$count = $row['countryCount'];
$countries = $row['country'];
echo $count;
echo $countries;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do:-

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_country, country FROM users GROUP BY country ORDER BY id DESC");

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) )
{
    $countries           = $row['country'];
    $total_countries = $row['total_country'];

    echo "<p>{$countries}</p>;
    echo "<p>Total count: {$total_countries}</p>";
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You're not assigning the variable.

Do this: `$count = $row['COUNT'];` and echo it. It should work

Comment: OP hasn't aliased their query's `count()` into a column named count so this won't work. DV not from me, fyi

Comment: Agreed with @MonkeyZeus